# Where multiples conditions EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following problem and that is that when a record does not have the `RequestAssignments` list it does not bring me the join and it does not bring me that record, I want it to bring me the join even if that list is null and if it is not null then I can filter by the data have that list in the where of multiple conditions

`RequestAssignments` is a relationship of 1 to a lot but it may be that at a time the list has nothing but I still want the record returned to me even if it is null.

```
var query = _mapper
                .ProjectTo<WorkTrayVm>(
                _unitOfWork
                .Requests
                .GetAllById(
                    a => !a.DeletedRecord
                    &&
                    (request.RequestNo == null || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.RequestNo) || a.RequestNo.ToLower().Contains(request.RequestNo.ToLower())))
                    &&
                    (!request.TypeId.HasValue || a.TypeId == request.TypeId)
                    &&
                    (!request.RefferalChanelId.HasValue || a.ReferralChannelId == request.RefferalChanelId)
                    &&
                    (!request.StateId.HasValue || a.StatusId == request.StateId)
                    &&
                    (!request.DateFrom.HasValue || a.EntryDate >= request.DateFrom)
                    &&
                    (!request.DateTo.HasValue || a.EntryDate <= request.DateTo)
                    &&
                    (a.RequestPeople.Any(aa => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.ComplaintNumber) || aa.People.Number.ToLower() == request.ComplaintNumber.ToLower())))
                    &&
                    (a.RequestAssignments.Any(aa => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Assgments) || aa.Assigned.Email.ToLower() == request.Assgments.ToLower())))                    
                    , false, false, request.PageNumber, request.PageSize))
                   .OrderByDescending(a => a.Id)
                   .ToList();
```

```
public class WorkTrayVm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RequestNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryDateDGII { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
    public int ReferalChannelId { get; set; }
    public string ReferalChannel { get; set; }        
    public List<CompaintRequestWorkTrayVm> Complaints { get; set; }        
    public List<DenouncePersonVm> Denounces { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }        
    public List<AssgnamentPerson> AssgnamentPersons { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int Process { get; set; } 
}

public class CompaintRequestWorkTrayVm 
{
    //public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public int DocumentTypeId { get; set; }
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surnames { get; set; }
}

public class DenouncePersonVm 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public int documentTypeId { get; set; }
    public string document { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surnames { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
} 

public class AssgnamentPerson 
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: We have to guess what `_unitOfWork` is, what `.Requests` is and what `.GetAllById` does. That said, apparently all you need is an additional condition `!a.RequestAssignments.Any() || a.RequestAssignments.Any(aa => ...`.

Comment: Can you work without `GetAllById` method? It is something weird.